# Do formatters need to write member's name to the stream when doing serialization?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading a book that talks about Runtime Serialization using `BinaryFormatter`, steps below are from the book:

1. The formatter calls FormatterServic upes's GetSerializableMembers method.

```
public static MemberInfo[] GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context);
```

This method uses reflection to get the type’s public and private instance fields (excluding any fields marked with the NonSerializedAttribute attribute). The method returns an array of MemberInfo objects, one for each serializable instance field.

2. The object being serialized and the array of System.Reflection.MemberInfo objects are then passed to FormatterServices' static GetObjectData method:

```
public static Object[] GetObjectData(Object obj, MemberInfo[] members);
```

3. The formatter writes the assembly's identity and the type's full name to the stream.
4. The formatter then enumerates over the elements in the **two** arrays, writing each member's **name** and **value** to the stream.

I have a question on the step-4. Let's take a concrete type for example:

```
[Serializable]
class Person {
   public int age = 20;
   public string name = "John";
   ...
}
```

the author says the formatter needs to write each member's name and value to the stream, so in this example, the formatter needs to write 20, "John", "age", "name" into the stream

But I feel that it is not necessary to write member's name to the stream, writing values will suffice. Because if you look at the core of the deserilize method: FormatterServices's PopulateObjectMembers method
[source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatterservices.cs,326)

```
// simplified version by me
public static object PopulateObjectMembers(object obj, MemberInfo[] members, object[] data) {
   ...
   MemberInfo mi;
   for (int i=0; i<members.Length; i++) {
      mi = members[i];
      if (data[i]!=null)
         SerializationSetValue(mi, obj, data[i]);
   }
   ...
   return object;
}
```

so you can see that `object[] data` is just 20, "John", so when you serilize the object in a specified order, and deserilize in the same order, there is no need to use member's name such as "age", "name", unless you serilize and deserilize in a different order and you want to use the member name to locate the correct `MemberInfo`.

So do formatters need to write member's name to the stream when doing serialization? or I misunderstand what the author really mean?

Comment: You might want to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide.  A quote: _"The **BinaryFormatter** type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing. Applications should stop using `BinaryFormatter` as soon as possible"_

Comment: If you don't write the name of the property, how can you deserialise  back it into the correct property?  It's possible that you save a V1 file (with 2 properties) and deserialise into a V2 program, that has 3 properties. If you don't store the property names, you have no idea how to deserialse.

Comment: @Neil But it looks like `FormatterServices.PopulateObjectMembers(object obj, MemberInfo[] members, object[] data)` method doesn't use member name, the `object[] data` contains purely values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up two things that are working together:

On one site, there is the `Serializable` attribute and its methods. This contains also the two methods `GetSerializableMembers()` to describe the structure and `GetObjectData()` to get the concrete values of a living instance that should be serialized. Regardless of the used writer (aka formatter) you'll always need a tree of key value pairs holding the property name as key and its content as value (which could be another object of key value pairs).

The next one comes into play is (in your case) the *binary formatter*. It consumes this structure and picks whatever it likes to, to write the information into some kind of stream. This *special implementation* of a fomatter is tried for being optimized for needed size within stream. This will be achieved by omitting the keys and only writing the value and assuming the reader knows the exact structure and writes the values onto the correct properties.

That's the reason, why this formatter shouldn't be used. Instead use some kind of serialization that also contains the structure like XML or JSON. These add also the keys to the stream and making it easier to deserialize the data even if the destination structure doesn't fully match.

Comment: but it looks like `MemberInfo[] members`  and `object[] data` have a one to one relationship, so as long as fields are serialized in an order, and the formatter deserialize fields in a same order, we don't need to serialize `members` at all since we can get a same one from the type during deserialization?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But that's the problem with BinaryFormatter. If you make any change to the transferred object structure the whole system breaks up.